# Azure SQLServerException posts upgrade

Tags: sql-server, azure, java-14

I recently updated from JAVA 12 to JAVA 14 and updated a lot of my libraries.  A newer version of spring, Azure libs, etc, etc.

However, upon trying to run my app with these new bells & whistles I'm getting the following error:

````
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Catalog view 'SEQUENCES' is not supported in this version.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:868)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:768)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:693)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeQuery(ProxyStatement.java:111)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyStatement.java)```

Has anyone come across this before?  IF so, any ideas?
````

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Using Azure Datawarehouse and the driver is ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Synapse Analytics (aka SQL Data Warehouse) does not support [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  You'll need to find what application component is attempting to create a sequence.  Upgrading the JDBC driver wouldn't cause this.